# How to count the appearence of particular

Tags: sql, oracle

Actually
as per the question
every employee should have at most 2 dependent
and i thought of doing in triggers
How do I implement that in SQL plus.

```
EMPNO |SSN
------|---
1     |1
1     |2
1     |3
2     |2
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many easy and reliable ways of doing this, but one way is through a fast refresh on commit materialised view, defined with a query such as:

```
select col1,
       count(*) c_star
from   my_table
group by col1;
```

... and with a check constraint placed on the c_star column to limit it to values less than or equal to 2.